# Using に as subject marker in non-passive/causative sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-に, passive-voice

In [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/31044/making-someone-feel-something) question I was given

> 「（私は）あの人に怒っている。」

as a way to say "that person makes me angry".

I'm a little confused because it looks to me very much like a passive construction, "I, that person by, get angered", but the predicate isn't in passive form. How should I understand the use of the particle に in this sentence?

Comment: In case my answer to your previous question was not clear, I never meant to use that に as the subject marker.  That is a natural Japanese sentence (because I only know how to say things naturally in Japanese).  It is not the direct translation of "That person makes me angry."    It is, instead, how a Japanese speaker would express the same idea expressed by that English sentence.  My point was that we use different sentence structures to say it.

Comment: Ya, as l'électeur notes, the Japanese above is not a direct translation of _"that person makes me angry."_  A closer English match would be _"I am angry **at** that person,"_ with the **at** corresponding to the **に**.

Comment: @l'électeur Your answer was very helpful. It's just that using に to mean 'at/with somebody' is entirely new to me, and I wasn't sure if I was understanding it correctly. I'm more used to it meaning 'by/for somebody'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should understand it as "I'm mad/angry **at** that person."

Like if you say 私に怒らないでよ！you're saying "well don't get mad **at** *me* about it!"

And the other way around if you say お母さんに怒られた。it means mum got angry **at** me.

Comment: 「お母さんに怒られた。」 is in passive voice.  = "(one was) scolded by (one's) Mom."  Stating "it means mum got angry at me." without any explanation, it could be fairly confusing to the learner.